# How to detect end-of-file when using freopen in C++?

Tags: c++, file, freopen

There's feof for fopen. But I am using

```
freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
```

What is the equivalent of feof for this?

Comment: I'm assuming `"w` is a typo and should be `"w"`

Comment: Why do you think it's different? Be careful with `feof` though. It's true after an attempt to read past the end of file. It doesn't tell you if you are just at the end of file.

Comment: There is `foef` "for" `freopen`. In general, there is `feof` for `FILE*`.

Comment: That would be `feof`

Comment: @Borgleader thank you, fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same as when the file was opened with `fopen`: You use `feof`.

For example, after `freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);`, `feof(stdin)` will tell you whether you hit the end of "in.txt".

The usual warning about `feof` applies: `feof` does not tell you whether you are at the end of the file *now* - it tells you *whether the last thing you tried to do failed* because you got to the end of the file. See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)